# How do I fetch data from nosql database in strict order?

Tags: firebase, go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I am using the Firestore database. I have to fetch the data from Firestore in a specific order.

My Approach:

I have a collection of documents in a collection named **section** with an integer field **order** that specifies where it lies on the page. So they basically have an order which is used to fetch data in a specific order by using `OrderBy("order")`. The order is also a parameter that can be given from the front-end side when creating a section.

But this has a drawback: When someone creates a section with the order that exists in the Firestore database, I have to basically create that section with the given **order** and increment the **order** field of all the section that comes after the created section by one. This is inefficient.

Secondly, I can create an array of integers that represent order and change the order in that array every time a section is created. So I don't have to hit the Firestore database and can make changes in the array itself. Is there any specific method to fetch data in the order as defined in some array?

I tried **in** keyword like `db.collection("section").Where("order", "in", []int{1,2,3})` but the result is not strictly in the order **1, 2, 3**

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I can think of would be to add a timestamp value inside your documents. In this case, you can create a query and order the results ascending. The first document will be the oldest added document. If you need to add a document in between two other documents, then you have to read the timestamp of the document before and the document after, and then set the timestamp in between. The precision of the Firestore timestamp is nanoseconds, this means that the risk of collision is not so high. However, in case you have two documents with the same timestamp, then you can add a second orderBy call.

Comment: How do i set the timestamp in between? Like taking average of the timestamp?
Can I use float or double instead of timestamp?
Does order by work with floating point numbers?

Comment: Yes, taking the average. Yes, you can also use floating-point numbers, and yes, the order works.

Comment: Hey Sandeep. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Comment: Yes, It certainly helped me. But for this specific problem we had a parent collection **pages**, we decided to implement the ordering in that parent collection and sort the child collection **section** everytime according to that order whenever we need to list the sections.

Comment: So you used timestamps or floating-point values?

Comment: Neither, As i mentioned in the above comment we used a different approach. We used sectionOrder as a field in firestore in pages collection that contains the ids of the sections in the required order and displayed sections in that order by sorting the sections obtained from firestore in memory according to the order of ids as in sectionOrder.